# How to discover all attributes supported by an object class in the Directory Context in LDAP

Tags: ldap, jndi, ldapconnection

I have been trying to find out a way to discover all the attributes supported by an object class in the Directory Context. I have tried to use `getattributes()` method of the Directory Context, but this displays only those attributes which are populated. I am interested in discovering all attributes supported only the specific object class, not all attributes for all object classes. The following are the code snippets that I have already tried.

//Approach 1

```
        System.out.println("using bindings.......");

        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope( SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE );
        searchControls.setReturningAttributes( new String[]
            { "objectClasses" } );
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = conn.getInitialContext().search( "cn=schema", "(ObjectClass=*)", searchControls );

        SearchResult result = results.next();
        Attributes entry = result.getAttributes();

        javax.naming.directory.Attribute objectClasses = entry.get( "objectClasses" );
        System.out.println( objectClasses );

        System.out.println("................................");
```

//Approach 2

```
        DirContext tedClasses = (conn.getInitialContext().getSchemaClassDefinition(entryName));

        // Enumerate the class definitions
        NamingEnumeration namingEnum = tedClasses.search("", null);
        System.out.println("attrs are:");
        while (namingEnum.hasMore()) {
            System.out.println(namingEnum.next());
        }
```

Where `conn.getInitialContext()` gives the directory context

Comment: You mention you have tried certain approaches.  Please show the code for those attempts.

Comment: Hi Sabuncu, I have updated the question with the approaches I have already tried.

Comment: Approach 2 is the correct solution. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

Can you perform an ldapsearch specifying `objectclass=x` (x being the objectclass you want)?

So searching for objectclass of person e.g.

```
ldapsearch -h <host> -p <port> -D <useraccount> -w \? -b <search string> objectclass=person
```